# Lambda chaining - Invoke lambda from another lambda using terraform

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to invoke one AWS lambda from another and perform lambda chaining. The rationale behind doing this is AWS does not provide multiple trigger from same S3 bucket.

I have created one lambda, with an s3 trigger. The java code of first lambda will listen to S3 event and contains the invocation of another lambda. The second lambda will be invoked from first lambda. Both the lambda creation is done by terraform.

Lambda A has S3 trigger. This will be invoked on S3 event on a particular bucket. Lambda A will do the processing and will invoke Lambda B using invoke request. Lambda B invocation from Lambda A code in java is :

```
public class EventHandler implements RequestHandler<S3Event, String> {
  @Override
  public String handleRequest(S3Event event, Context context) throws RuntimeException {
    InvokeRequest req = new InvokeRequest()
    .withFunctionName("LambdaFunctionB")
    .withPayload(json);
    return "Lambda B invoked"
  }
}
```

Both the lambdas are created using terraform. Scripts below:

Lambda A terraform:

```
module "lambda_function" {
   source = "Git Path"
   absolute_artifact_path = "../lambda.jar"
   lambda_function_name = "LambdaFunctionA"
   lambda_function_description = ""
   lambda_function_runtime = "java8"
   lambda_handler_name = "EventHandler"
   lambda_execution_role_name = "lambda-iam-role"
   lambda_memory = "512"
   dead_letter_target_arn = "error-handling-arn"

}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_bucket" {
  statement_id  = "statementId"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = "${module.lambda_function.lambda_arn}"
  principal     = "s3.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = "s3.bucket.arn"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "bucket_notification" {
  bucket = "bucketName"

  lambda_function {
    lambda_function_arn = "${module.lambda_function.lambda_arn}"
    events              = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
    filter_prefix       = "path/subPath"
  }
}
```

Lambda B terraform:

```
module "lambda_function" {
   source = "git path"
   absolute_artifact_path = "../lambda.jar"
   lambda_function_name = "LambdaFunctionB"
   lambda_function_description = ""
   lambda_function_runtime = "java8"
   lambda_handler_name = "LambdaBEventHandler"
   lambda_execution_role_name = "lambda-iam-role"
   lambda_memory = "512"
   dead_letter_target_arn = "error-handling-arn"

}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_lambda" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromLambda"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = "${module.lambda_function.lambda_arn}"
  principal     = "s3.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:xxxxxxxxxx:function:LambdaFunctionA"
}
```

lambda-iam-role has below policies attached

```
AmazonS3FullAccess
AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
AmazonSNSFullAccess
CloudWatchEventsFullAccess
```

Expectation was that Lambda A should successfully invoke Lambda B. But I am getting AccessDeniedException in Lambda A logs and it is not able to invoke Lambda B. Error is

```
com.amazonaws.services.lambda.model.AWSLambdaException: User: arn:aws:sts::xxxxxxxxx:assumed-role/lambda-iam-role/LambdaFunctionA is not authorized to perform: lambda:InvokeFunction on resource: arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:xxxxxxxxx:function:LambdaFunctionB (Service: AWSLambda; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: f495ede3-b3cb-47a1-b884-16996545233d)
```

Answer (score 7):

- Hope this helps you, not exactly similar but its invoking one lambda from another lambda [Github](https://github.com/amittn/lambda-invoking-lambda)
- I think the lambda needs this policy as well "lambda:InvokeFunction"

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer online, using the aws-sdk.

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');

var lambda = new aws.Lambda({

  region: 'default'

});

lambda.invoke({

  FunctionName: 'name_of_your_lambda_function',

  Payload: JSON.stringify(event, null, 2) // pass params

}, function(error, data) {

  if (error) {

    context.done('error', error);

  }

  if(data.Payload){
   context.succeed(data.Payload)

  }

});
```

You can find the doc here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html

Hope it helps
:)